# Como resolver o erro QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>' no PyQT5 usando threading para atualizar interface gui

Tags: python, syntax-error, pyqt

Boa noite,

Sou iniciante na area do python, e estou com dificuldade na parte de threading juntamente com uma interface gui, criada no QT Desegner.
conversando com uns amigos me indicaram este forum, pois talvez pudessem me ajudar/esclarecer qual o problema.
Acontece que não entendo muito dessa area, comecei a poucos meses, e estou tentando aprender sozinho com base em exemplos / videos da internet. fiz o seguinte codigo de exemplo:

```
from PyQt5 import  uic,QtWidgets
import time
import threading

def atualiza_dados():
    a = 0
    while 1:
        time.sleep(2)
        tela.label_6.setText(str(a))
        tela.tabela1.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('Valor de A: '))
        tela.tabela1.setItem(0, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(a)))
        a += 1

app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
tela=uic.loadUi("tela_monitor.ui")
tela.tabela1.setRowCount(1)
threading.Thread(target=atualiza_dados,daemon=True).start()
tela.show()
app.exec()
```

O codigo acima, incrementa a variavel "a" e adciona o valor  dentro de uma label, e dentro de uma linha que por sua vez está dentro de uma tabela. porem estou usando uma threading para executar o loop infinito e não congelar a janela principal. mas rodando o programa eu consigo atualizar somente o valor da label, somente atualiza o valor da tabela quando eu clico nela.
outro problema é que aparece as seguintes mensagens no cmd ao executar o programa:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

Se eu deixar somente a label, ele não da os erros acima, porem quando adciono a tabela da erro.

Inseri duas imagens da tela também para tentar ilustrar melhor o que está acontecendo.

Vocês poderiam me ajudar a resolver este problema? desde já muito obrigado.

[image: Nesta imagem aparece a atualização somente da label]

[image: Nesta imagem aparece a atualização da tabela e da label, porem depois que cliquei na janela conforme mencionei acima.]

@edit segue o codigo do arquivo ui, pois esqueci de adciona-lo..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>508</width>
    <height>252</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>18</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: rgb(85, 85, 255);
background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Monitoramento</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>18</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Valor de A:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>46</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: rgb(85, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tabela1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>240</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>251</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Nome</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Valor</string>
     </property>
    </column>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>508</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei exatamente qual a natureza do erro que você vê, mas acredito que seja por alguma incompatibilidade entre o sistema de threads do Qt e do Python. O ideal é que, ao usar o PyQt, você utilize o sistema de threading provido por eles. Há diversos tutoriais por aí mostrando as diferentes formas e módulos do PyQt que você pode usar para rodar uma função em uma thread separada da interface - por exemplo, [aqui](https://www.mfitzp.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/) e [aqui](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/) (links em inglês).

Abaixo há um exemplo mínimo mostrando uma interface semelhante à sua, que atualiza o contador exibido a cada 2 segundos (tentei criar algo semelhante já que não tenho acesso ao seu arquivo .ui):

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw, QtCore as qtc


class MyApp(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Contador que atualiza ao chamar self.update
        self.a = 0  # valor inicial
        
        # Layout do meu app
        layout = qtw.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        # Label estático "Monitoramento"
        self.monitoramento_label = qtw.QLabel("Monitoramento")
        layout.addWidget(self.monitoramento_label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        
        # Label estático "Valor de A"
        self.valor_a_label = qtw.QLabel("Valor de A")
        layout.addWidget(self.valor_a_label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        
        # Tabela
        self.table = qtw.QTableWidget(rowCount=1, columnCount=2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Nome", "Valor"])
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, qtw.QTableWidgetItem("Valor de A"))
        self.table.setItem(0, 1, qtw.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.a)))
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 1, 2, 1)
        
        # Label dinâmico - exibe o valor de self.a
        self.a_label = qtw.QLabel(str(self.a))
        layout.addWidget(self.a_label, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        
        # Timer - responsável por chamar o método self.update
        # a cada 2000 milissegundos (2 segundos)
        self.timer = qtc.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(2000)

    def update(self):
        """Incrementa self.a em um e atualiza a interface em seguida."""
        self.a += 1
        self.a_label.setText(str(self.a))
        self.table.setItem(0, 1, qtw.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.a)))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MyApp()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Resultado (se você rodar o código, verá o contador sendo incrementado):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segredo aqui está no objeto `QTimer`, nas linhas:

```
self.timer = qtc.QTimer()
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
self.timer.start(2000)
```

Aqui, criamos o objeto, conectamos ele ao método `self.update` e pedimos para ele chamar este método a cada 2000 milissegundos (2 segundos).

Note que o código que escrevi envolve a definição de uma classe `MyApp` e dos seus métodos `__init__` e `update` - caso você não esteja familiarizado com essas coisas, recomendo estudar mais sobre **programação orientada a objetos**. Vai te ajudar bastante a entender melhor sobre PyQt e Python em geral.

Note também que escrevi os elementos da interface (os labels, a tabela etc) diretamente no código. Dessa forma, não é necessário utilizar o Qt Designer para montar a interface (isso é um pouco de preferência pessoal, mas eu prefiro escrever todo o código da interface porque fica mais fácil de me localizar quando a interface começa a ficar mais complexa).

Comment: primeiramene gostaria de agradecer por ter respondido, então muito obrigado.
Vou ler os dois links que vc deixou no começo no topico, obrigado.
Realmente seu exemplo faz exatamente o que eu queria, meu arquivo ui é bem simples semelhante mesmo ao que vc fez, realmente não entendi o conceito da classe MyApp e dos seus métodos __init__ e update não estou familiarizado com eles, no caso eu teria que escrever meu codigo dentro da classe? quanto aos elementos diretamente no codigo achei bem interessante o metodo que vc fez. irei procurar mais sobre programacao orientada objetos.

Comment: Desculpe duplicar o comentario, mas acabou os caracteres, eu tentei passar a parte do qtc.QTimer() para o meu codigo porem a janela ficou travada. isso quer dizer que não funciona sem criar a classe certo?

Comment: Oi Gabriel, que bom que minha resposta foi útil :) você está certo, basicamente toda a biblioteca do PyQt só vai funcionar dentro de classes. O PyQt nada mais é do que uma "tradução" da biblioteca Qt (escrita em C++) para Python, e como essa bilbioteca funciona dentro de um paradigma de orientação a objetos, o código em Python também deve ser escrito dessa forma, com widgets representados por classes e objetos. Talvez até exista alguma forma de fazer o código funcionar sem usar classes, mas deve envolver alguma gambiarra não suportada oficialmente.

Comment: Entendi, está certo então, muito obrigado por responder. irei estudar mais. vou tentar aprender esse conceito das classes etc. obrigado pela ajuda.